# PUT vs POST when a time updated is being tracked

Tags: http, post, put

I have a 6NF-esque schema in part of my database, where any time a property value is changed, a new row is created with the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. For example

```
+----------+-------+---------+
| EntityID | Value | TimeSet |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 |   foo | 1:30 PM |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 |   bar | 1:31 PM |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

So, the PK is `EntityID, TimeSet` (TimeSet is a MySQL `TIMESTAMP` - I just used readable values for the example). Any `GET` requests will `SELECT` the latest value for the entity only (i.e. `GET /entities/1/<property>` would return `bar` only).

As of right now, there are no behaviors that depend on the time set, it's just there for auditing. My question is: when I want to set values for this attribute over HTTP, should I be using `PUT` or `POST`? Technically, a new row is being created every time the user sends a value, but from the standpoint of the API, the request is idempotent, because you could create 100 rows of the same value, and only the most recent one will be returned for any `GET` requests.

Answer (score 1):

Meaby this can help you:
The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. POST is designed to allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:

```
  - Annotation of existing resources;
  - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list,
    or similar group of articles;
  - Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a
    form, to a data-handling process;
  - Extending a database through an append operation.
```

The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: This is helpful, but I still see cases for both methods. I'm certainly annotating existing resources, and I'm extending the database through an append operation. However, I am also storing the value at the supplied request URI. So, `GET entities/1/<property>` will get the most recent value set by `PUT entities/1/<property>`

Comment: By convention you need to use PUT, but for security reasons you can use POST, if you certainly know that everything is safe use PUT, otherwise use POST.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at things with a resource perspective. Though you are just updating a value with a timestamp, you are actually creating a new resource on the server and not modifying the old one. Returning the latest timestamped resource is actually part of your business logic and should not be confused with a PUT/POST request.

So, the right answer is use a POST request.

Comment: here's the thing, from the prospective of the entire application, each of those rows does not represent an actual resource. They are just properties describing a different resource (`EntityID`), so, while I'm creating a row in the DB, I'm really just updating the resource specified by the URI. The only thing that can even see multiple rows is the DBAL, which only returns the latest value to the rest of the application.

Comment: Okay then. Is this just a case of your schema handling object properties differently ? If yes, I think this is because your object properties are not defined before time in the schema ?